# stop background scrolling when covering page with a css cover?

Tags: css

Can someone please tell me, i am using a cover to create a (white) blackout effect on page load, below is the css I'm using. Is there a way i can stop the mouse scroll being able to move the page in the background up and down?

```
#cover {
display:none;
position:absolute;
z-index:999999;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:2648px;
background-color:#fff;
filter:alpha(Opacity=50);
opacity:0.7;
-moz-opacity:0.7;
-khtml-opacity:0.7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution would probably be to add "overflow: hidden;" to you body, while page is loading, and remove it on page load.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using Height:2648px which of course is higher than most screens and therefor creating the scroll.

You can fix this by using

**CSS**

```
#cover {height:100%;}
```

**Overflow Method**

```
#cover {overflow:none;}
```

Additional I'm not sure why the height is 2648px in the first place but if your having aspect ratio issues with overflow or height:100% use **[media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)** to fix on devices that are having problems.

Comment: ok fixed height and tried overflow:none but still allows user to scroll down the page when the css cover is in place. :/ is there any other way i can get the background to lock or set the css cover to lock on a ratio of the screen of some kind.